# Plotting a graph using data from SQL Server, running on nodejs and displaying on html

Tags: html, sql-server, node.js

So far I can connect to my database in server.js and I can query my database and see results on terminal. Showing the information in html, or better yet, plotting and displaying a graph in html, is proving quite difficult. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For graphs and other stuff there is [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).